# Not able to connect to kafka-connect using docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I am using docker-compose.yml file for my Kafka setup and this is working as expected. As I am trying to connect to oracle database, I need to install ojdbc driver as well. So, I have modified my compose file to directly download ojdbc jar but after adding this code, I am not able to start Kafka-connect.

**Additional code added in the file :**

```
 command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - /
          cd /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/
          curl https://maven.xwiki.org/externals/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar -o ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar
          /etc/confluent/docker/run
```

I had also tried to start the Kafka-connect container manually but it's not working as well. If you could see in the below screenshot, all services got created successfully.

[image]

**Full docker-compose.yml file:**

```
    ---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
    hostname: kafka-connect
    container_name: kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: kafka-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

    command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - /
          cd /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/
          curl https://maven.xwiki.org/externals/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar -o ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar
          /etc/confluent/docker/run 

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.9.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.9.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - kafka-connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.4.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

Comment: what is the error? if you are going to download packages its not a good idea to include in a entrypoint script or in a command, create another dockerfile that inherits and add the packages and then run the new image, want me to help you with that?

Comment: There is no error as such. It's just not getting started like other containers. I guess including jar in this way is a very convenient and preferred way. More details here :https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this got resolved, after adding this line at bottom in the command section:

```
sleep infinity
```

> sleep infinity is necessary, because we’ve sent the
>   /etc/confluent/docker/run process to a background thread (&) and so
>   the container will exit if the main command finishes.

More details here : https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/